# Can I make automatic import another Components via loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, routes

I have imports at the top of JavaScript file (React.js):

```
import Home from "./Home";
import Login from "./Login";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
...
```

And I want to 'automatic' this process with loop

```
let arr = [Home]; 
for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  import Home from "./Home";
}
```

But got this error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Can I do this in another way?

Comment: Is your goal to write less code (while still statically import everything on boot)? Or is your goal to decide at runtime which components to import, and then load them dynamically?

Comment: first option: less code

Comment: Then you cannot do that in javascript. The first example you gave is the way to do imports, and only minor variations are possible. The only way i can think to do something kind of like your second example is with a pre-processor as part of your build process. For example, you could write a webpack pre-processor which edits your files, turning them into the code in example 1. That seems like a lot of work for little gain though.

Comment: You could create named exports for those defaults. That would look like `import { Home, Login, Dashboard } from './pages'`.

Comment: But, what is wrong with import in loop. is it bound of syntax language or it's more seriously reason?

Comment: Assuming you're using a bundler (eg, webpack), the import statements say which files should be included in the bundle. That needs to happen at compile time. A for loop can't execute until runtime. So trying to do a compile-time import via a run-time loop is impossible. It is possible to do dynamic imports (ie, the second part of my original question), but then you're going to be creating promises at runtime, not static imports at compile time.

Comment: Thanks! everything is clear!